# Is there a way to export issues from BHM for import into BizTalk Terminator?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, mbv, bhm

Is there a way to export issues from the BizTalk Health Monitor, for import into BizTalk Terminator? ... in a similar way to the Message Box Viewer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With BHM v3, we added Terminator functionality into BHM itself.  So you no longer need to manually copy over the MBVCleanupScripts.xml.  Simply selecting the "From Latest BHM Report" task category will provide you the tasks that BHM is proposing.  See the following link for more info:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/biztalkcpr/archive/2015/06/29/biztalk-terminator-now-available-via-bhm.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The BizTalk Health Monitor generates the same reports as the Message Box Viewer on the following location:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\BizTalkHealthMonitor\BizTalkGroup\MBVOutput_20xx-Xx-Xx_Xx-Xx-Xx_MyMBVReport
```

You should be able to find the "MBVCleanupScripts.xml" file over there.